# What is a good free subscribe list?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, email, signup

I tried 3 different plugins and they ALL didn't work.
I would like a plugin that allows me to put a widgit into the sidebar. Configure a redirect page to say thank you and a way to get a list of the emails (preferably with signup date and name. csv is nice)

Is that so much to ask for...

If it can shoot everyone an email on signup that be nice too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you could do. It is more of like three plugins. One main plugin and two that are sub plugins

First you will want to get Contact Form 7 ... if you don't already have it. Here is the link if you need it:

[Download Contact Form 7 Here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Then download Contact Form 7 to Database. This will store whatever information you collect in the form in your database.

[Download Contact Form 7 to Database Here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/)

Our last and final plugin download is the Contact Form 7 Sidebar widget. You can get it here:

[Contact Form 7 Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-widget/)

After you have all that where you edit the contact form just add this bit of a javascript hook in the additional settings for the redirect:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

Replace "http://example.com/" with your own url.

Comment: You are very welcome. :)